# How to compute $\prod\limits^{\infty}_{n=2} \frac{n^3-1}{n^3+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, infinite-product

> How to compute
>   $$\prod^{\infty}_{n=2} \frac{n^3-1}{n^3+1}\ ?$$

My Working :

$$\prod^{\infty}_{n=2} \frac{n^3-1}{n^3+1}= 1 - \prod^{\infty}_{n=2}\frac{2}{n^3+1}
=  1-0 = 1$$

Is it correct

Comment: It would have been true if $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n-b_n) = \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n - \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$. Sadly, it's not...

Comment: Try factorization of numerator and denominator.

Comment: What @Kunnysan, plus note that $(n+1)^2-(n+1)+1 = n^2+n+1$.

Comment: Maple produces $$product((1-1/n^3)/(1+1/n^3), n = 2 .. infinity) $$  $$\frac 2 3 ,$$ product(1-1/n^3, n = 2 .. infinity) $$1/3\,{\frac {\sin \left( \pi \, \left( 1/2+1/2\,i\sqrt {3} \right) 
 \right) }{\pi }},
 $$ and $$product(1+1/n^3, n = 2 .. infinity) $$ $$1/2\,{\frac {\sin \left( \pi \, \left( 1/2+1/2\,i\sqrt {3} \right) 
 \right) }{\pi }}.
 $$ The imaginary parts equal zero.

Comment: From where can I get the details on telescoping series.. please suggest thanks... to all of you..

Comment: This infinite product , along with $$\prod^{\infty}_{n=2} \frac{n^2-1}{n^2+1}$$            and                                       $$\prod^{\infty}_{n=2} \frac{n^4-1}{n^4+1}$$ are discussed in "Experimentation in Mathematics" Borwien, Bailey, Girgensohn (2004).

Answer (score 12):

Magic answer:

Let $f(n) =\dfrac{n(n-1)}{n^2-n+1}$. Then show $f(n+1) = \dfrac{n(n+1)}{n^2+n+1}$ and thus $$\frac{f(n)}{f(n+1)} = \frac{n(n-1)(n^2+n+1)}{n(n+1)(n^2-n+1)} = \frac{n^3-1}{n^3+1}$$

(I call this a "magic answer" just because most of the other answers here give you reasons for how you would see this, while I just plop in an $f$ that works, as if by magic. This is really the same argument as the others, just distilled to a minimalist essence.)

Answer (score 8):

HINT:

If $$t_n=\frac{n^3-1}{n^3+1}=\frac{(n-1)(n^2+n+1)}{(n+1)(n^2-n+1)}$$

$$t_{n+1}=\frac{n\{(n+1)^2+n+1+1\}}{(n+2)\{(n+1)^2-(n+1)-1\}}=\frac{n\{(n+1)^2+n+1+1\}}{(n+2)(n^2+n+1)}$$

and $$t_{n-1}=\frac{(n-2)\{(n-1)^2+n-1+1\}}{n\{(n-1)^2-(n-1)-1\}}=\frac{(n-2)(n^2-n+1)}{n\{(n-1)^2-(n-1)-1\}}$$

---

Alternatively, let $\displaystyle u_n=\frac{n-1}{n+1},v_n=\frac{n^2+n+1}{n^2-n+1}$ so that $t_n=u_n\cdot v_n$

$$\implies\prod_{2\le n\le r}u_n=\frac{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdots(r-2)(r-1)}{3\cdot4\cdot5\cdots r(r+1)}\frac2{r(r+1)}$$

$$\implies\prod_{2\le n\le r}v_n=\frac{7\cdot13\cdot21\cdots(r^2-r+1)(r^2+r+1)}{3\cdot7\cdot13\cdots \{(r-1)^2-(r-1)+1\}(r^2-r+1)}=\frac{r^2+r+1}3$$

$$\implies\prod_{2\le n\le r} t_n=\left(\prod_{2\le n\le r}u_n\right)\left( \prod_{2\le n\le r}v_n\right)=\frac{2(r^2+r+1)}{3r(r+1)} $$

Setting $r\to\infty,$  $\displaystyle \frac{2(r^2+r+1)}{3r(r+1)}=\frac23\lim_{r\to\infty}\frac{1+\frac1r+\frac1{r^2}}{1+\frac1r}=?$

Comment: From where can I get the details on telescoping series.. please suggest thanks... to all of you..

Comment: You mean, other than googling "Telescoping Series" and finding the Wikipedia page? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series

Comment: @sultan, just set $n=1,2,3,\cdots$ in the first method to see which terms survive. My hint shows that there will be ample cancellations. Also, please find the alternative method

Answer (score 5):

Note that
$${n^3 - 1 \over n^3 + 1} = {n - 1 \over n + 1}{n^2 + n + 1 \over n^2 - n + 1}$$
Also note that
$$(n-1)^2 + (n - 1) + 1 = n^2 - n + 1$$
So the infinite product in question is really the product of two telescoping products.

Comment: From where can I get the details on telescoping series.. please suggest thanks... to all of you..

Comment: The idea is that if you multiply the terms of a telescoping series, the numerator of a given term will be cancelled by a corresponding denominator from a different term. So multiplying them together will lead to a lot of cancellation, and you will be able to find the limit quite easily.

Answer (score 0):

$$\dfrac{r^3-a^3}{r^3+a^3}=\dfrac{r-a}{r+a}\cdot\dfrac{r^2+ra+a^2}{r^2-ra+a^2}$$

Let $f(r)=r^2-ra+a^2$

$$f(r+h)=(r+h)^2-(r+h)a+a^2=r^2+r(2h-a)+a^2-ah$$

If we set $r^2+ra+a^2=f(r+h),$

$$r^2+ra+a^2=r^2+r(2h-a)+a^2-ah$$

Comparing the coefficients of $r,$ $$a=2h-a\iff h=a$$

Compare the constants $a^2=a^2-ah+h^2\iff h(h-a)=0$

$\implies h=a,$  $$r^2+ra+a^2=f(r+a)$$

$$\dfrac{r^3-a^3}{r^3+a^3}=\dfrac{f(r+a)}{f(r)}\cdot\dfrac{g(r-2a)}{g(r)}\text{ where } g(m)=m+a$$

Clearly 
$$\prod_{r=1}^n\dfrac{f(r+a)}{f(r)}\cdot\dfrac{g(r-2a)}{g(r)}$$ telescopes for finite integer $a$