# How to find the value of the infnite product $\frac {7}{9}$x$\frac {26} {28}$x $\frac {63} {65}$x . . . x$\frac {n^3-1} {n^3+1}$x . .

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How to find the value of the infnite product

$\frac {7}{9}$x$\frac {26} {28}$x $\frac {63} {65}$x . . . x$\frac {n^3-1} {n^3+1}$x . .

Somebody please help me.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/462082/how-to-solve-this-prod-infty-n-2-fracn3-1n31

Comment: It is much easier if you start with $n=1$ (: