# Finding the value of this product

Tags: limits

How do I find the value of the product $P$?

$P=\displaystyle\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\displaystyle\prod_{a=5}^{n}\dfrac{a^3-64}{a^3+64}$

This was in a test I gave, but I wasn't able to solve it.

Comment: Note that $64 = 4^3$. Factorise numerator and denominator.

Comment: @DanielFischer I did that..

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/462082/how-to-solve-this-prod-infty-n-2-fracn3-1n31

Comment: As brilliant as Daniel Fischer is, unfortunately, he's not psychic, @Pkwssis. In future please share your thoughts on your questions :)

Answer (score 4):

$$\displaystyle\prod_{a=5}^{n}\dfrac{a^3-64}{a^3+64}=\prod_{a=5}^n\dfrac{a-4}{a+4}\prod_{a=5}^n\frac{a^2+4a+16}{a^2-4a+16}$$

Now, $$(a+4)^2-4(a+4)+4^2=a^2+4a+16$$

So setting $\displaystyle F(n)=n-4, G(n)=n^2-4n+16,$ the product can be written as $$\prod_{a=5}^n\frac{F(a)}{F(a+8)}\prod_{a=5}^n\frac{G(a+4)}{G(a)}$$ inviting cancellation of most of the terms

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $a^3 - 64 = (a-4) ( a^2 + 4a + 16)$

Hint: $a^3 + 64 = (a+4) ( a^2 - 4a + 16)$

Hint:

> $(a+4) ^2 - 4 (a+4) + 16 = ??$