# Compute $\prod\limits _{r=3 }^{\infty }{ \frac { { r }^{ 3 }-{ 8 } }{ { r }^{ 3 }+{ 8 } } } $

Tags: limits

How should I go about evaluating this product? I have not been able to figure out.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod _{r=3 }^{n  }{  \frac { { r }^{ 3 }-{ 8 } }{ { r }^{ 3 }+{ 8 } } } $$

Comment: Hint: Concatenate $$\frac { r^3-8}{ r^3+8}=\frac {r-2}{r+2}\cdot\frac{(r+1)^2+3}{(r-1)^2+3}.$$

Comment: Hint:
$$\frac{r^3-8}{r^3+8}=1-\frac{16}{r^3+8}$$

Comment: @Elaiwi This yields the convergence of the infinite product, not its value.

Comment: @SanchayanDutta, See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/462082/how-to-solve-this-prod-infty-n-2-fracn3-1n31

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$$\begin{align}
\prod_{n=3}^{N}\frac{n^3-8}{n^3+8}&=\prod_{n=3}^{N}\frac{(n-2)(n^2+2n+4)}{(n+2)(n^2-2n+4)}\\\\
&=\prod_{n=3}^{N}\frac{(n-2)}{(n+2)}\prod_{n=3}^{N}\frac{(n+1)^2+3}{(n-1)^2+3}\tag 1
\end{align}$$

---

Now, analyzing the individual partial products we see that the first partial product reduces to

$$\begin{align}
\prod_{n=3}^{N}\frac{(n-2)}{(n+2)}&=\frac{1}{5}\frac{2}{6}\frac{3}{7}\frac{4}{8}\frac{5}{9}\cdots\frac{N-6}{N-2}\frac{N-5}{N-1}\frac{N-4}{N}\frac{N-3}{N+1}\frac{N-2}{N+2}\\\\
&=\frac{(1)(2)(3)(4)}{(N-1)(N)(N+1)(N+2)} \tag 2
\end{align}$$

while the second partial product reduces to

$$\begin{align}
\prod_{n=3}^{N}\frac{(n+1)^2+3}{(n-1)^2+3}&=\frac{4^2+3}{2^2+3}\frac{5^2+3}{3^2+3}\frac{6^2+3}{4^2+3}\cdots \frac{(N-1)^2+3}{(N-3)^2+3}\frac{(N)^2+3}{(N-2)^2+3}\frac{(N+1)^2+3}{(N-1)^2+3}\\\\
&=\frac{(N)^2+3}{2^2+3}\frac{(N+1)^2+3}{3^2+3}\tag 3
\end{align}$$

---

Putting $(2)$ and $(3)$ into $(1)$ yields

$$\begin{align}
\prod_{n=3}^{N}\frac{n^3-8}{n^3+8}&=\frac27 \frac{(N^2+3)((N+1)^2+3))}{(N+2)(N+1)(N)(N-1)}
\end{align}$$

from which we can easily see that

$$\begin{align}
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\prod_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{n^3-8}{n^3+8}=\lim_{N\to \infty}\prod_{n=3}^{N}\frac{n^3-8}{n^3+8}=\frac27}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Isn't this what @Vincenzo explained, plus a colored frame at the end?

Comment: @did It took a while to type this as I was called away from the computer for a while.  This is a bit more explicit version and provides a "visual" way of seeing the terms that cancel.  It might ptovide for some a primer-type answer.

Answer (score 9):

As an expansion of Did's comment, recognize the difference and the sum of cubes in the general factor to see the product can be rewritten as $$\prod_{r=3}^{\infty} \frac{(r-2)(r^2+2r+4)}{(r+2)(r^2-2r+4)}=   \prod_{r=3}^{\infty}\frac{r-2}{r+2}\frac{(r+1)^2+3}{(r-1)^2+3},$$ which makes clear that the $r$-th denominator of the first fraction and the $r+4$-th numerator of it, as well as  the $r$-th numerator of the second fraction and the $r+2$-th denominator of it will cancel each other, leaving $$\prod_{r=3}^\infty \frac{r^3-8}{r^3+8}= \frac{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4}{7\cdot12}=\frac{2}{7}.$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: show by induction that $$\prod_{r=3}^k\frac{r^3-8}{r^3+8}=\frac{2(3+k^2)(4+2k+k^2)}{7(k-1)k(k+1)(2+k)}$$

Comment: compute the limit, and thx for downvoting

Comment: Is this thread about [you](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c10h454208) it certainly increases my tolerance levels ;).

Comment: and did you get the limit with the other hints?

Comment: One problem with your answer is that the right hand side of the equality you propose the OP to prove is produced *ex nihilo*. Why would anyone even consider proving what you tell them? While following your hint will certainly solve the actual question, absolutely no enlightment will ensue.

Comment: It seems that comments taking the Doc to task for the appalling defects of some of their answers are routinely and silently deleted. Is this a mod intervention? Isn't the equivalent of a signpost saying "rubbish" a worthy piece of information to passing by users, regarding answers that are, in effect, rubbish? That the Doc is *never* addressing these remarks is no excuse, on the contrary.