# Prove $\prod_{k=2}^N\left(1-\frac{2}{k^3+1}\right)~=~\frac23\left(1+\frac1{N(N+1)}\right)$

Tags: induction, infinite-product

I am struggling to verify the following

$$\prod_{k=2}^N\left(1-\frac{2}{k^3+1}\right)~=~\prod_{k=2}^N\left(\frac{k^3-1}{k^3+1}\right)~=~\frac23\left(1+\frac1{N(N+1)}\right)$$

I tried to use induction but failed at simplifing. My attempt so far

---

First of all set $N=2$

$$\begin{align}
\frac{2^3-1}{2^3+1}~&=~\frac23\left(1+\frac1{2(2+1)}\right)\\
\frac79~&=~\frac79
\end{align}$$

Next set $N=M$ and further $N=M+1$ to get

$$\begin{align}
\prod_{k=2}^M\left(\frac{k^3-1}{k^3+1}\right)~&=~\frac23\left(1+\frac1{M(M+1)}\right)\\
\prod_{k=2}^{M+1}\left(\frac{k^3-1}{k^3+1}\right)~&=~\frac23\left(1+\frac1{(M+1)(M+2)}\right)
\end{align}$$

By splitting up the second product and substitute the first formula in we get

$$\begin{align} 
\frac23\left(1+\frac1{(M+1)(M+2)}\right)~&=~\prod_{k=2}^{M+1}\left(\frac{k^3-1}{k^3+1}\right)\\
&=~\prod_{k=2}^M\left(\frac{k^3-1}{k^3+1}\right)\left(\frac{(M+1)^3-1}{(M+1)^3+1}\right)\\
&=~\frac23\left(1+\frac1{M(M+1)}\right)\left(\frac{(M+1)^3-1}{(M+1)^3+1}\right)\\
&=~\frac23\left(\frac{M(M+1)+1}{M(M+1)}\right)\left(\frac{(M+1)^3-1}{(M+1)^3+1}\right)\\
&=~\frac23\left(\frac{(M+1)^2-M}{(M+1)^2-(M+1)}\right)\left(\frac{(M+1)^3-1}{(M+1)^3+1}\right)
\end{align}$$

And this were I got stuck. Removing the parentheses and then rewrite everthing leads nowhere. Could someone please help me with this task?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compute $\prod\limits^{\infty}_{n=2} \frac{n^3-1}{n^3+1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/462082/how-to-compute-prod-limits-infty-n-2-fracn3-1n31)

Comment: It is not exactly what I have asked for. I know how to compute the value of the infinite product by the given formula for a upper bound $N$. I attempted to prove this formula for a whole number $N$ without going up to infinity. My focus is on the proof not on the value at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$1-\frac{2}{k^2+k+1}=\frac{k^3-1}{k^3+1}
=\frac{k-1}{k+1}\frac{k^2+k+1}{k^2-k+1}
=\frac{k-1}{k+1}\frac{k^2+k+1}{(k-1)^2+(k-1)+1}.$$
Then
$$\prod_{k=2}^N\left(1-\frac{2}{k^2+k+1}\right)
=\prod_{k=2}^N\frac{k-1}{k+1}\times
\prod_{k=2}^N\frac{k^2+k+1}{(k-1)^2+(k-1)+1}.$$
Both these products telescope:
$$\prod_{k=2}^N\frac{k-1}{k+1}=\frac2{N(N+1)}$$
and
$$\prod_{k=2}^N\frac{k^2+k+1}{(k-1)^2+(k-1)+1}
=\frac{N^2+N+1}{3}$$
etc.

Comment: This is a way different than my approach, so I have to ask: It is even possible to show this by using induction?  - or, in other words, it is worth a try to fix my attempt without getting into way to complicated equations?

Comment: @mrtaurho to fix your approach I'd divide $$\frac23\left(1+\frac1{M(M+1)}\right)$$ by $$\frac23\left(1+\frac1{(M-1)M}\right)$$ and hope to get $$\frac{M^3-1}{M^3+1}.$$

Comment: Ah, okay. Thank you for your time and your help. I will try to keep this trick in my mind.