# Find $\lim_{n \rightarrow\infty } P_n$whreas $P_n=\frac{2^3-1}{2^3+1}\cdot\frac{3^3-1}{3^3+1}\cdot\cdot\cdot\frac{n^3-1}{n^3+1}$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

$\lim_{n \rightarrow\infty }  P_n$whreas $P_n=\frac{2^3-1}{2^3+1}\cdot\frac{3^3-1}{3^3+1}\cdot\cdot\cdot\frac{n^3-1}{n^3+1}$.

This is a past problem of a high-school level math compettion.

My tries:

1.Initially I thought of finding the product of the sequence.But then I realize there is no need of product coz' it'll make the function more complicated.

2.Then I tried to simplify first few terms so that may be in some way some of the middle terms may be cancelled out .

So the product of first few terms look sth like this,

$\frac{7}{9}\cdot\frac{26}{28}\cdot\frac{63}{65}\cdot\cdot\frac{n^3-1}{n^3+1}$

But I could'nt find any pattern in this.So how  the limit can be evaluated?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/462082/how-to-compute-prod-limits-infty-n-2-fracn3-1n31

Comment: $\displaystyle 2/3$ is the solution (explicitly).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's some telescoping going on here. We have
$$\frac{n^3-1}{n^3+1}=\frac{n-1}{n+1}\frac{n^2+n+1}{n^2-n+1}.$$
Then
$$\prod_{n=2}^N\frac{n-1}{n+1}=\frac13\frac24\frac35\frac46\cdots\frac{N-1}{N+2}$$
and
$$\prod_{n=2}^N\frac{n^2+n+1}{n^2-n+1}=\frac73\frac{13}7\frac{21}{13}\frac{31}{21}\cdots\frac{N^2+N+1}{N^2-N+1}.$$
Both these products telescope to give a closed form for
$$\prod_{n=2}^N\frac{n^3-1}{n^3+1}.$$

Comment: But I have no idea  about the telescoping !!Can't be there some other simple ways!!

Comment: @Invnto he actually gave the answer. Look more closely.

Comment: yeah!! Now I got it !!Actually I haven't observed the solution properly!!

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\bbox[10px,#ffd]{P_{n}} & \equiv
\prod_{k = 2}^{n}{k^{3} - 1 \over k^{3} + 1} =
\prod_{k = 2}^{n}{\pars{k - 1}\pars{k - \expo{2\pi\ic/3}}
\pars{k - \expo{-2\pi\ic/3}} \over
{\pars{k + 1}\pars{k - \expo{\pi\ic/3}}
\pars{k - \expo{-\pi\ic/3}}}}
\\[5mm] & =
{\pars{n - 1}! \over \pars{n + 1}!/2}\prod_{k = 2}^{n}{\pars{k - \expo{2\pi\ic/3}}
\pars{k - \expo{-2\pi\ic/3}} \over
\pars{k - \expo{\pi\ic/3}}\pars{k - \expo{-\pi\ic/3}}}
\\[5mm] & =
{2 \over \pars{n + 1}n}\verts{\prod_{k = 2}^{n}
{\pars{k - \expo{2\pi\ic/3}} \over \pars{k - \expo{\pi\ic/3}}}}^{2}
\\[5mm] & =
{2 \over n\pars{n + 1}}\verts{\prod_{k = 2}^{n}
{\pars{k + 1/2 - \root{3}\ic/2} \over
\pars{k - 1/2 - \root{3}\ic/2}}}^{2}
\\[5mm] & =
{2 \over n\pars{n + 1}}
\verts{\pars{5/2 - \root{3}\ic/2}^{\overline{n - 1}} \over
\pars{3/2 - \root{3}\ic/2}^{\overline{n - 1}}}^{2}
\\[5mm] & =
{2 \over n\pars{n + 1}}
\verts{\Gamma\pars{n + 3/2 - \root{3}\ic/2}/\Gamma\pars{5/2 - \root{3}\ic/2} \over
\Gamma\pars{n + 1/2 - \root{3}\ic/2}/\Gamma\pars{3/2 - \root{3}\ic/2}}^{2}
\\[5mm] & =
{2 \over n\pars{n + 1}}\,\verts{\Gamma\pars{3/2 - \root{3}\ic/2} \over \Gamma\pars{5/2 - \root{3}\ic/2}}^{2}\
\verts{\pars{n + 1/2 - \root{3}\ic/2}! \over
\pars{n - 1/2 - \root{3}\ic/2}}^{2}
\\[8mm] & \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ n\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}\,\,\,
{2 \over n\pars{n + 1}}\
\overbrace{1 \over \verts{3/2 - \root{3}\ic/2}^{2}}^{\ds{=\ 1/3}}\
\times
\\[2mm] &
\verts{\root{2\pi}\pars{n + 1/2 - \root{3}\ic/2}^{n + 1 - \root{3}\ic/2} \expo{-n - 1/2 + \root{3}\ic/2} \over
\root{2\pi}\pars{n - 1/2 - \root{3}\ic/2}^{n - \root{3}\ic/2}
\expo{-n + 1/2 + \root{3}\ic/2}}^{2}
\\[8mm] & \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ n\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}\,\,\,
{2/3 \over n\pars{n + 1}}\
\verts{n^{n + 1 - \root{3}\ic/2}\bracks{1 + \pars{1/2 - \root{3}\ic/2}/n}^{n} \expo{- 1/2 + \root{3}\ic/2} \over
n^{n - \root{3}\ic/2}\bracks{1 - \pars{1/2 + \root{3}\ic/2}/n}^{n}
\expo{1/2 + \root{3}\ic/2}}^{2}
\\[5mm] & =
{2/3 \over n\pars{n + 1}}\,n^{2}
\,\,\,\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ n\ \to\ \infty}{\Large\to}\,\,\,
\bbx{2 \over 3}
\end{align}

Comment: Not sure this is the method intended for a high school competition :P

Comment: @YiFan Unfortunately, I agree with you. Anyway, it's an alternative. At least I show that the answer is $\displaystyle 2/3$. Thanks.