# Prove that $\prod\limits_{n= 2}^{\infty} \frac{n^{3}+ 1}{n^{3}- 1}= \frac{3}{2}$, which is a beautiful value!

Tags: limits, proof-verification, complex-numbers, fractions, infinite-product

*Prove that* $\prod\limits_{n= 2}^{\infty} \dfrac{n^{3}+ 1}{n^{3}- 1}= \dfrac{3}{2}$, *which is a beautiful value ! A solution due to **a p u** as follow*
$$\begin{align}
\prod\limits_{n= 2}^{\infty} \frac{n^{3}+ 1}{n^{3}- 1} & = \prod\limits_{n= 2}^{\infty}\frac{(n+ 1)(n+ \omega )(n+ \omega^{2})}{(n- 1)(n- \omega )(n- \omega^{2})}\\ 
 & = \prod\limits_{n= 2}^{\infty} \frac{(n+ 1)(n- 1- \omega)(n- 1- \omega^{2})}{(n- 1)(n- \omega )(n- \omega^{2})}\,(\!1+ \omega+ \omega^{2}= 0\,used\!)\\ 
 & = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{n(n+ 1)(1- \omega)(1- \omega^{2})}{1\cdot 2(n- \omega)(n- \omega^{2})}\\ 
 & = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{3(1+ \frac{1}{n})}{2(1- \frac{\omega}{n})(1- \frac{\omega^{2}}{n})}\,\left (\!(1- \omega)(1- \omega^{2})= 1+ 1+ 1= 3\,used\!\right )\\ 
 & = \frac{3}{2}
\end{align}$$
*I have a solution, and I'm looking forward to seeing a nicer one(s), thanks for your interests a lot !*

Comment: How do you go from the infinite product to the lim ?

Comment: what is $\omega$?

Comment: @Klangen from context, it is a third [root of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity).

Comment: @Klangen $\omega$ is a root of unity: $\omega = \exp(\frac{2 \pi i}{3})$

Comment: @quarague by partial products. Most terms cancel out

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @JMoravitz I gathered as much, I only wanted to point out that the question was incomplete...

Comment: @Randall to see if there is a cleaner or more elegant way to evaluate the given infinite product than what is shown above by the OP.

Comment: My question is actually better in terms of context ... I want you could leave it alone ! Please !

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Can you unmark it?

Comment: @HanhVyheaven28, Unmark duplicate?

Comment: Yes, I think it doesn't matter if I have another way to get this !

Comment: @HanhVyheaven28, Why do you want that?

Comment: What is **a p u** here?

Comment: ***a p u*** is a nickname of my friend !

Comment: I posted it because I want to see another approachs, I'm so sorry, I didn't notice the duplicate ! But if I have a duplicate, why I can't try it, even if it's better ?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I also show my try ! Can you consider my opinion ?

Comment: @HanhVyheaven28, Done! But, Much better way is to write your approach in the linked post

Comment: ROGER THAT ! Thank you sir !

Comment: $\lceil$ *https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/462082/how-to-compute-prod-limits-infty-n-2-fracn3-1n31?noredirect=1&lq=1* $\rfloor$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a much simpler way. Observe that the partial product

$$
\prod_{n=2}^{m} \frac{n^3+1}{n^3-1} = \frac{3 (m^2+m)}{2(m^2+m+1)}.
$$

Then when $m\to\infty$, the product converges to $\displaystyle \frac{3}{2}$.

Comment: +1 How did you find this formula?

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks! Here is an old post with some details: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/462082/how-to-compute-prod-limits-infty-n-2-fracn3-1n31?noredirect=1&lq=1