# topic for factoring $n^5−n$ is divisible by 5 general case

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I understood the hypothesis induction and the inductive step 
*$(k+1)^5−(k+1)$*

How to factor it to this one:
$$=(k^5+5k^4+10k^3+10k^2+5k+1)−(k+1)\\=k^5+5k^4+10k^3+10k^2+5k−k\\=(k^5−k)+5k^4+10k^3+10k^2+5k$$

Comment: You do not mean "factor", that is, recognize a product and its factors, but "expand", transform the compact expression into the monomial form.

Comment: One way of doing this without induction is to note $n^5-n=n(n^4-1)=n(n^2-1)(n^2+1)=$$=n(n+1)(n-1)(5+(n+2)(n-2))=5n(n+1)(n-1)+n(n+1)(n-1)(n+2)(n-2)$ which is the sum of an obvious multiple of $5$ (the first part) and the product of five consecutive integers, which must therefore be divisible by $5$.  In fact this can be used to show that $n^5-n$ is divisible by $30$ (since it is divisible by the product of three consecutive integers, which guarantees a factor $6$)

Comment: ** LutzL** ,got it/

Comment: **Mark Bennet** Thank you.

Comment: Since $n^5-n=120\binom{n}{5}+240\binom{n}{4}+150\binom{n}{3}+30\binom{n}{2}$, we can see that $30\mid n^5-n$ for all integer $n$.

Comment: @cisco_guy: Given that $5\mid k^5-k$, you have shown $(k+1)^5-(k+1)=\underbrace{\left(k^5−k\right)}_{\text{divisible by $5$ by hypothesis}} +\underbrace{5k^4+10k^3+10k^2+5k}_{\text{divisible by $5$}}$

Comment: @Arthur: $2^5-2=30$ which is not divisible by $120$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/462082/how-to-compute-prod-limits-infty-n-2-fracn3-1n31/3276050#3276050

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just the binomial theorem, remember Pascal's triangle
\begin{array}{rc}
(a+b)^0=&1\\
(a+b)^1=&a+b\\
(a+b)^2=&a^2+2ab+b^2\\
(a+b)^3=&a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+b^3\\
(a+b)^4=&a^4+4a^3b+6a^2b^2+4ab^3+b^4\\
(a+b)^5=&a^5+5a^4b+10a^3b^2+10a^2b^3+5ab^4+b^5
\end{array}

---

Once you understood how to expand the power $(k+1)^5$, you can conclude from your last line that
$$
(k+1)^5-(k+1)=[k^5-k]+5(k^4+2k^3+2k^2+k)
$$
where the first term is divisible by 5 per induction hypothesis, and the second term as it has an explicit factor $5$.

---

#### direct solution

You do not need to solve this per induction, as first shown in the question comment of @MarkBennet, you can directly factorize using binomial theorems
$$
n^5-n=n(n^2-1)(n^2+1)=n(n-1)(n+1)\Bigl(5+(n-2)(n+2)\Bigr)
$$
so that you get one term which has an explicit factor $5$ and another term that is the product of the consecutive numbers $(n-2),(n-1),n,(n+1),(n+2)$, of which one is divisible by $5$.

Additinally, among the common factors $(n-1),n,(n+2)$, at least one is divisible by 2 and one divisible by $3$, so that the whole expression is divisible by $2\cdot 3\cdot 5=30$.

---

In general it is known that for any prime $p$ one has
$$
x^p-x=x(x+1)(x+2)\cdots(x+p-1)\pmod p
$$

Comment: actually, it is familiar but l didn't learn it.

Comment: Great, it was very helpful, I understood the holes in my knowledge

Answer (score 0):

To answer a surmised question from the title.
n$^5$ - n = n(n$^2$ + 1)(n$^2$ - 1)
is divisible by 5 because 
n = 5m + k for some m and k = 0,1,2,3, or 4.
Show for each k, that one of the factors is divisible by 5.
Use n$^2$ = 25m$^2$ + 10mk + k$^2$.

Jumping into the very middle of a proof has created an incomprehensible question.

Comment: It looks like you didn't read the comments. Specifically Mark's comments, 21 minutes ago.