# compute $\prod_{n=2}^{N} \frac{n(n+1) +1}{ n(n-1)+1}$ .

Tags: real-analysis, infinite-product

I am not able to compute this infinite product and so I am asking for help here.

> Compute the product $\prod_{n=2}^{N} \frac{n(n+1) +1}{ n(n-1)+1}$ .

I tried by factoring $\frac{n(n+1) +1}{ n(n-1)+1}$ into  $(1+ \frac{2n}{n^2-n+1}) $ but this doesn't seems to help and I don't  have any other ideas.

Please help.

Comment: Numerator cancels previous denominator. So it will ultimately be (n(n+1)+1)/3

Comment: Compute the first few terms explicitly & then notice that there will be telescopic cancellation.

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/462082/how-to-compute-prod-limits-infty-n-2-fracn3-1n31

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a telescopic product, for $ N\geq 2 $, we have : \begin{aligned} \prod_{n=2}^{N}{\frac{n^{2}+n+1}{n^{2}-n+1}}=\prod_{n=2}^{N}{\frac{\left(n+1\right)^{2}-\left(n+1\right)+1}{n^{2}-n+1}}&=\frac{\left(N+1\right)^{2}-\left(N+1\right)+1}{2^{2}-2+1}\\ &= \frac{N^{2}+N+1}{3}\end{aligned}

A telescopic product, has the form of $ \prod\limits_{k=p}^{q}{\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_{k}}}=\frac{a_{q+1}}{a_{p}} $, were $ p,q\in\mathbb{N} $, such that $ q\geq p $, and $ \left(a_{k}\right)\in\left(\mathbb{R}^{*}\right)^{\mathbb{N}} $.