# Proving $\prod_{k = 2}^{\infty} \frac{k^3 - 1}{k^3 + 1}=\frac{2}{3}$ more rigorously

Tags: solution-verification, infinite-product

**Problem:** What is $\prod_{k = 2}^{\infty} \frac{k^3 - 1}{k^3 + 1}$?

**My Approach:** We can rewrite as
$$\prod_{k = 2}^{\infty} \frac{k^3 - 1}{k^3 + 1} = \left(\prod_{k = 2}^{\infty} \frac{k - 1}{k + 1}\right)\left(\prod_{k = 2}^{\infty} \frac{k^2 + k + 1}{k^2 - k + 1}\right).$$
We can see the first product approaches by pattern as
$$ \prod_{k = 2}^{\infty} \frac{k - 1}{k + 1} = \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(\frac{2}{4}\right)\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)\left(\frac{4}{6}\right)\cdots = \lim_{N \to \infty}\frac{2}{N}.$$
Similarly,
$$\prod_{k = 2}^{\infty} \frac{k^2 + k + 1}{k^2 - k + 1} = \left(\frac{7}{3}\right)\left(\frac{13}{7}\right)\left(\frac{21}{13}\right)\cdots = \lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{N}{3}.$$
Therefore,
$$\prod_{k = 2}^{\infty} \frac{k^3 - 1}{k^3 + 1} = \lim_{N \to \infty}\frac{2}{N}\times \lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{N}{3} = \lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{2}{3} = \frac{2}{3}.$$
This doesn't feel rigorous enough to me because I'm just looking at the pattern. Is there anything I can do to make this a better proof?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compute $\prod\limits^{\infty}_{n=2} \frac{n^3-1}{n^3+1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/462082/how-to-compute-prod-limits-infty-n-2-fracn3-1n31) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cprod_%7Bk%3D2%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%5Cfrac%7Bk%5E3-1%7D%7Bk%5E3%2B1%7D%24&p=1). As for your approach, you shouldn't split the $2$ product limits apart since one limit, i.e., $\frac{2}{N}$ goes to $0$, while the other one, i.e., $\frac{N}{3}$, goes to $\infty$. FYI, there's also several AoPS threads that deal ...

Comment: Lok at expression for large N

Comment: (cont.) with the reciprocal of your product instead, e.g., [Please Help](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1452387p8338212), [Random Algebra Question](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1281460p6742477), etc. Last, but not least, welcome to Math SE.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I guess it kind of does, but I don't really see any approach that did something similar to mine. I was looking for some constructive criticism on how to make my proof better, is that not allowed on this forum?

Comment: The limit thing makes sense, so then what should I try?

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.

Comment: If you don’t split the limits, your proof is okay. You could also prove that there indeed is a pattern. For $(k-1)/(k+1)$, this is not necessary. For $f(k)=k^2+k+1$ and $g(k)=k^2-k+1$, you can note $f(k)=g(k+1)$

Comment: Ypur idea is fine, but use instead $$\prod_{k = 2}^{M} \frac{k - 1}{k + 1} = \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(\frac{2}{4}\right)\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)\left(\frac{4}{6}\right)\cdots = \frac{2}{M(M+1)}$$

$$\prod_{k = 2}^{M} \frac{k^2 + k + 1}{k^2 - k + 1} = \left(\frac{7}{3}\right)\left(\frac{13}{7}\right)\left(\frac{21}{13}\right)\cdots = \frac{M^2+M+1}{3}$$ then take the limit.